# No CSS and JS files when deploying with Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my project to `heroku`, but I faced a problem: there is no `CSS` and `JS` in deployed site. When I open page source of deployed site, for example here is next script in page source:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="/static/static/scripts/validation.js">
```

When I go to src link, it shows internal error. I guess that if my scripts were saved somewhere in Inet and src would be a link to it, then it would work correct. But when deploying my site, all my `scripts` and `CSS`are in `static` folder. When run site locally, it's okay, when through `heroku`, it can't see `CSS` and `scripts`. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: Did you read the very comprehensive [Heroku doc on Django assets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relative path linking use static template tag.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "somepath/validation.js" %} ">
```

set `STATIC_ROOT` and run `python manage.py collectstatic`

Check the Heroku doc for [Django and Static Assets](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets)
Official  documentation for [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/).